# Will there be a performance benefit in the upgrade for iPod touch 5 to iPod touch 6 for the KNFB reader?

Tags: accessibility

A totally blind user wants to make use of the [KNFB reader](http://www.knfbreader.com/) but does not want a cell phone, some of the reviews I have read suggest that it works best on the iPhone 6, other reviews suggest that that iPod touch 5 is a suboptimal version of the iPhone 5.  I have near zero knowledge about smart phones and less about apple devices.

Is it possible to tell if an iPod touch 5 will provide the same level of function with the KNFB reader as users are seeing with the app on the iPhone 6?

Comment: I would imagine that the iPhone 6, since it has technology that is two years closer to current than the iPod touch 5, including a much better camera, would work better, but I don't know that for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no iPod Touch 6. In fact, the iPod Touch hasn't been updated in 2 years and even at launch did not have as good a camera as the the iPhone 5 it was introduced with (the iPod Touch camera is coverable to the iPhone 4S or maybe even the iPhone 4?). I can't speak about the KNFB reader specifically, but the newest iPhone (6 and 6 plus) are much faster than the iPod Touch 5 from 2012, so no, the older hardware in the iPod Touch 5 cannot provide the same level of functionality.

Whether the functionality in the ipHone 6 is enough of an improvement to make the cost worthwhile is a question only the user can answer.

Comment: +1 As the KNFB reader is a converts images to audio text, it sounds like waiting for the iPod Touch 6 to launch is the better choice, she has been without out until now, waiting a couple more months should be fine.

Comment: I would not assume there will be an iPod Touch 6 in a few months.